# Is there a way to control which special forms Normal converts?

Tags: expression-manipulation, core-language, undocumented

[`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) documentation reads:

> Normal[*expr*] converts *expr* to a normal expression, from a variety of special forms.

But is there a way to control which special forms it converts and which it does not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Yes.

It turns out that `Normal` accepts an undocumented second parameter which may be a Symbol or a list of Symbols and it will only affect those forms.  Plain application converts all these forms (and more):

```
abby = {
  SparseArray[{3 -> "a", 5 -> "b"}],
  <|1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"|>,
  Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 5}],
  Quantity[1, "Percent"]
 };

abby // Normal
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, "a", 0, "b"},
>  {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}, 
>  1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + x^4/24 + x^5/120,
>  1/100}
> ```

We can target the specific forms like this:

```
abby ~Normal~ SparseArray
abby ~Normal~ Quantity
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, "a", 0, "b"},
>  <|1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"|>,
>  SeriesData[x, 0, {1, 1, 1/2, 1/6, 1/24, 1/120}, 0, 6, 1],
>  Quantity[1, "Percent"]}
>
> {SparseArray[< 2 >, {5}],
>  <|1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"|>,
>  SeriesData[x, 0, {1, 1, 1/2, 1/6, 1/24, 1/120}, 0, 6, 1],
>  1/100}
> ```

Or multiple types with:

```
abby ~Normal~ {SeriesData, Association}
```

> ```
> {SparseArray[< 2 >, {5}],
>  {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}, 
>  1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + x^4/24 + x^5/120,
>  Quantity[1, "Percent"]}
> ```

---

#### Usage note *and correction*

Previously I wrote that `Normal` passes over held expressions.  It does not.

Some cases could be handled equivalently with a simple replacement like:

```
expr /. sa_SparseArray :> Normal[sa]
```

However evaluation is not equivalent such as within a held expression:

```
held = Hold @@ abby

held /. sa_SparseArray :> Normal[sa]

held ~Normal~ SparseArray
```

> ```
> Hold[
>  Normal[SparseArray[< 2 >, {5}]],
>  <|1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"|>,
>  SeriesData[x, 0, {1, 1, 1/2, 1/6, 1/24, 1/120}, 0, 6, 1],
>  Quantity[1, "Percent"]
> ]
>
> Hold[
>  {0, 0, "a", 0, "b"}, 
>  <|1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"|>,
>  SeriesData[x, 0, {1, 1, 1/2, 1/6, 1/24, 1/120}, 0, 6, 1],
>  Quantity[1, "Percent"]
> ]
> ```

Comment: Igor approves. +1

Comment: MapAt[Normal,abby,1]? Just kidding, I can see the potential if you don't know what kind of data types will be returned and you want to get rid of a specific one (Quantity would be my target, I guess).

Comment: @Sjoerd To catch expressions at all levels one would need something like `expr /. q_Quantity :> Normal[q]` which is fine but a bit less clean.  There is also a difference in held expressions, e.g. `Hold[Quantity[5, "Percent"]]` would return `Hold[Normal[Quantity[5, "Percent"]]]` with the rule above while `Normal` would simply pass over that expression; one would need to add a skip rule like `/. {x : _Hold | _HoldForm | _HoldComplete :> x, q_Quantity :> Normal[q]}` to approach that behavior and it would still miss user functions with a hold attribute so that would require further testing.

Comment: As of version 10.x, this feature appears to be [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html)

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks. That is not in the version 10.1.0 documentation.  I wonder when it was added.

Comment: It's there since at least 10.3 (I just checked); so it must have been added at some point in between.