# How to define Normal for new "data types"

Tags: expression-manipulation, customization, conversion

In *Mathematica* 9 and earlier, one of the points under "**Details**"/"**More Information**" section for the function [`Normal`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okg2F.png) was (this is gone after version 10):

[image]

I have defined my own "data types" and would like to define `Normal` for them to be converted to normal expressions.  How do I make this definition?  (undocumented functionality for an efficient answer is encouraged)

### Example

Here is a "data type" called `FractionSum`, and it is a data structure containing a list of three items:

```
expr = FractionSum[{Item1 :> a, Item2 :> b, Item3 :> c}]
```

Then I would like the following behavior:

```
expr // Normal
```

> `1/a + 1/(a+b) + 1/(a+b+c)`

Comment: Are you intending to self-answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I am asking sincerely.  Do you have an answer?

Comment: Would you please tell me the ways in which my present answer is lacking that are important to you, so I can try to improve it if i have time?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So sorry; by starting a bounty I didn't mean to snub your answer, which I think is very good.  I am looking to see if there is a proper way to do it (as the older documentation suggests) without hacking or modifying built-in functions.

Comment: okay, no problem

Answer (score 8):

I may be overlooking a deeper aspect of this question but a quick and dirty [`UpSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed.html) definition appears to work:

```
Normal[FractionSum[rules : {__}]] ^:= 
  1/Item1 + 1/(Item1 + Item2) + 1/(Item1 + Item2 + Item3) /. rules


expr = FractionSum[{Item1 :> a, Item2 :> b, Item3 :> c}]

expr // Normal
```

> ```
> 1/a + 1/(a + b) + 1/(a + b + c)
> ```

This doesn't work with `foo[expr] // Normal` however (it does not match) so maybe:

```
Unprotect[Normal]

Normal[x_ /; ! FreeQ[Unevaluated@x, _FractionSum]] := 
 Normal[
   x /. FractionSum[rules : {__}] :>
     (1/Item1 + 1/(Item1 + Item2) + 1/(Item1 + Item2 + Item3) /. rules)
 ]

Protect[Normal]
```

This still is not equivalent within held expression as described in the now-corrected **Usage note** section of [Is there a way to control which special forms Normal converts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84783/is-there-a-way-to-control-which-special-forms-normal-converts/84784#84784)  I shall continue to contemplate how this might be improved along with Leonid's admonition about modifying a System function in this way.

Comment: Why not `TagSetDelayed`? It is usually cleaner than `UpSetDelayed` (although in this particular case it doesn't matter). Also, why *should* it work on `foo[expr]`? I don't see any reason to request or expect that. And, I would really avoid redefining `Normal` like that (via `DownValues`) - it may have many undesired consequences.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin To be clear, I want `Normal` to act on my "data type" just as it acts on built-in ones.  This means it *should* work on `foo[expr]`.

Comment: @Leonid (1) `^:=` makes definitions for all heads at level one but there is only one head here so I would argue that `^:=` is *cleaner* if a little less explicit.  (2) `foo[SparseArray[{1}]] // Normal` (3) I acknowledge that redefining any System function may have undesired consequences but I don't see why this one would be especially dangerous.  Could you be more specific? *edit* I see that the way I wrote my code could lead to an infinite loop but that's a somewhat separate issue.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard (1) I view `TagSetDelayed` as a cleaner method precisely because it is more selective, so you always explicitly specify the symbol to which the rule is attached. I think this is good. (2) I didn't know about this, but actually I think this particular behavior / design choice was / is bad design. Allowing `Normal` to have non-local effects and going through expressions is just bad. (3) `Normal` is a pretty popular function. As such, it is called often enough in various parts of the system. As a rule, redefining such functions is bad, because you can't anticipate the consequences.

Comment: @Leonid (1) I guess I'll just agree to disagree, mindful of the fact that at least 80% of the time I end up agreeing with you later.  Do you presently use UpSet for anything? (2) Quite a surprise!  I could certainly see the value of *adding* a function that only operates directly but having `Normal` operate within expressions is very useful and I make use of that with some regularity.  But you have made me look at `Normal` again with new eyes and I see that some of my past beliefs were wrong!  `Quantity` will disregard Hold attributes which I had convinced myself it respected.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin (3) Is there a safer way to extend `Normal` to user data types?  I still feel that the first definition is fairly safe because it only triggers on a specific user Symbol.  The second definition is disagreeably general but I cannot think of a better way to do it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [1/2] (1) I like the "agree to disagree" idiom :). A somewhat similar-sounding one that I also like translates from Russian as "promise to promise" (typically used to characterize politicians). Re: `UpSet` - not really, I guess I don't want to actually upset the system. Seriously, I always use `TagSet` / `TagSetDelayed` (2) I generally think that structural operations like `Normal`  which act on various data types, should treat them as black boxes. Replacing stuff inside that data expression is a strong violation of this principle. Basically, if you have `Normal` act on the head...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [2 / 2] ...only (but not inside), you can always use rules to also do replacements inside expressions, if you want to. But if you have `Normal` and similar to automatically transform stuff, it is much harder to prevent that when it is not needed. So,  such design of `Normal` violates several principles of good design: information-hiding, encapsulation, minimal action. (3) If you mean this extended `Normal` behavior when it replaces stuff inside nested expressions, then I am not aware of good methods. But as I said, I dislike the whole idea. For heads proper, just usual  `UpValues`.

Comment: I'm leaving a little something for y'all's consideration: `SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> RootSum[1 + # + #^3 &, Sqrt[#] &], {2, 2} -> 1 + O[x]}, {2, 2}] // Normal`. But I do agree with Leonid that `TagSetDelayed` is a nicer thing, if only because I prefer attaching transformation rules to the custom symbols as opposed to built-in ones (see e.g. [my dual numbers answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13926)).

Answer (score 3):

using `TagSetDelayed` as pointed by @J.M. and @Leonid

```
FractionSum /: Normal[FractionSum[{patt : RuleDelayed[_, _Symbol] ..}]] := 
With[{sym = {patt}[[All, 2]]}, 
Plus @@ (Power[#, -1] &@Table[First@ListCorrelate[ConstantArray[1, i], sym], 
{i, Length@sym}])]

FractionSum[{Item1 :> a, Item2 :> b, Item3 :> c}] // Normal

(* 1/a + 1/(a + b) + 1/(a + b + c) *)
```

Comment: What I actually had in mind when using `TagSetDelayed[]` was something like `FractionSum /: Normal[FractionSum[{patt : RuleDelayed[_, _Symbol] ..}]] := (* stuff *)`...

Comment: @J.M. thanks ! edited